# Why it is impossible for primitive Pythagoras triplets in integers to be all as powerful numbers?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I had seen an elementary proof for Fermat's last theorem at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Did-Fermat-have-a-proof-for-his-Last-Theorem-or-was-he-just-bluffing).

I had checked all the steps (around one page only), where I couldn't catch any error, but I was confused about the last step only that includes the main idea that depends on a right angle triangle (in integers), are impossible to be with all sides being as powerful integers, the author claims this is too elementary to prove, but I don't see why this must be true?, there must be a counter example in large numbers (say more than six digits)!
or this might have a simple proof as stated!

So, can we find such a counter example or prove it simply?

Comment: There is no elementary proof of Fermat's last theorem, so whatever you read was probably nonsense. Are you maybe asking about [Fermat's right triangle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_right_triangle_theorem)? Your question is also not so clear.

Comment: Most likely you are right!, but mathematics is really surprising, if we can prove this conjecture independently then it would be more than sufficient to prove Beal's conjecture also, so the best way is to find a single primitive triplet with all terms being as powerful integers and relax from this proposition!

Comment: One can link to a web page in a posting here, [like this](en.wikipedia.org), and I think it would help if you did that with the page on Quora. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for providing the editing my question with link to the last answer

Comment: Previously I had asked a similar question [here] (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/242027/can-we-find-primitive-pythagoras-triplet-in-integers-with-two-sides-being-as/242050#242050).

Comment: @EricTressler We can only say that no elementary proof of Fermat's last theorem is known, not that no such proof exists. But I agree that such a proof would be very surprising.

Comment: I think, if a fact is confirmed or proved, then there must be many ways to arrive at it, note here I'm considering FLT which was proved first by Sir Andrew wile's and Taylor in 1995

Comment: Why don't we ask @bassamkarzeddin, the author of the mentioned Quota-post.

Comment: I had asked him at Quora, but I think he is planing something else, he was complaining about this site of hiding his documented discoveries without being able to refute them (despite he is not a mathematician), however there are still few of his posts visible, I think he wants a large number of people discover this fact at the same time, where suddenly an elementary proof is discovered by so many profs. then it would create an ethical state in mathematics as "who and why at sudden such  a proof is claimed by so many", where as it remained a mys. for many centuries", conflict is the aim!

Comment: I know that a bounty is very less reword for this question, but few millions dollars would be awaiting the correct answer!, but hopefully the answer wouldn't be so long as taking you to another galaxies, but few pages only that should had been known many centuries back!

Comment: @SophyanGharz why do we need to prove it independently, to prove Beal's conjecture? I think it's simple to prove from Fermat's last, is it not?

Comment: @Robert Frost I think FLT is only special case of Beal's conjecture, so proving FLT doesn't include Beal's, that is why it is still an open problem!

Comment: @SophyanGharz but I don't think that explains why it's necessary to prove the above conjecture independently of FLT does it?

Comment: If proven independently, then yes as claimed by the author, it can include Beal's that also includes FLT, to see this, consider a right angle triangle with coprime sides as the following, ($2x^ny^m, x^{2n} - y^{2m}, x^{2n} + y^{2m}$), where ($n, m$) are positive integers > 1,

Answer (score 4):

The Quora "proof" does not actually claim to be a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem - that there is no solution of $$x^n+y^n=z^n$$ for $n>2$.

It claims to be a proof that there is no solution of $$x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}=z^{p-1}$$ for $p-1>2$. Thus it would say nothing about (for example) $x^3+y^3=z^3$ or $x^5+y^5=z^5$.

So the result only deals with *certain* even values of $n$, and not with any of the odd ones.

**The start is promising.** Eliminating awkward cases by simple modular arguments has a long and respectable history.

However, although the arguments in part (a) are ingenious, they are not necessary. If it is true in general that $$(x^m)^2+(y^m)^2=(z^m)^2$$ has no solutions, then this does not depend on the parity of $x$, $y$, and $z$. In fact it doesn't even require $n=p-1$, only $n=2m$, and **it is a good simple proof of the $n=2m$ case.**

But I would appreciate a reference to the sides of a Pythagorean triangle not all being perfect $m$th powers.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to up vote your answer, also thanks to Bassam Karzeddin who originated this problem and also offered a modest bounty for this question, even your analysis are good enough but the main idea of the OP is covering all the cases not mentioned in the partial proof, it is partly as this which is more general than you had already shown, this integer equation ($x^{2n} + y^{2m} = z^2$), doesn't have any solution in non zero coprime integers ($x, y, z$),  and ($n, m$) are positive integers > 1,  this is only a remarkable and particular case of the generalization!, proof requid.

Comment: For a reference you require, I had asked in history section and still waiting an answer, as far as I could know, this was originated by the same author at Quora, about the parity of $x, y$, I think it is a must as stated in the post and must not be ignored since we are dealing with even exponents, which is ultimately Pythagoras identity, !

Comment: I've got a feeling the permissible number of odd and even factors in the edges can't be accommodated by powerful numbers.